# How to download Teams chat message attachments using the Microsoft Graph Beta API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

A `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl` is not available for chat message attachments using the Microsoft Graph Beta api.

I recently posted an issue in the `msgraph-sdk-javascript` repo concerning downloading Microsoft Teams chat message attachments through the beta graph api.

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/issues/200

The issue is that there is currently no way to obtain a `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl` for these chat attachments.  I have posted a workaround there that is as follows but that requires an additional api call and is possibly fragile as it involves parsing the chat attachment's `contentUrl`.

```
function getDownloadUrl(attachment: ChatMessageAttachment, team?: Team): string {
  const url = new URL(attachment.contentUrl as string);
  const path = url.pathname.split('/').slice(4).join('/');
  if (team) {
    return `/groups/${team.id}/drive/root:/${path}`;
  } else {
    return `/me/drive/root:/${path}`;
  }
}
```

I was asked by a `microsoft-graph-javascript` maintainer to post my question here.